# How to do numpy like conditional assignment in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The following is how it works in Numpy

```py
import numpy as np

vals_for_fives = [12, 18, 22, 33]
arr = np.array([5, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5])
arr[arr == 5] = vals_for_fives  # It is guaranteed that length of vals_for_fives is equal to the number of fives in arr

# now the value of arr is [12, 2, 3, 18, 22, 33]
```

For broadcastable or constant assignment we can use `where()` and `assign()` in Tensorflow. How can we achieve the above scenario in TF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tf.experimental.numpy.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/numpy/where) is a thing in `tensorflow v2.5`.

But for now you could do this:

First find the positions of the `5`'s:

```
arr = np.array([5, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5])
where = tf.where(arr==5)
where = tf.cast(where, tf.int32)
print(where)
# <tf.Tensor: id=91, shape=(4, 1), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])>
```

Then use `scatter_nd` to "replace" elements by index:

```
tf.scatter_nd(where, tf.constant([12,18,22,23]), tf.constant([5]))
# <tf.Tensor: id=94, shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([12,  0,  0, 18
, 22])>
```

Do a similar thing for the entries that were not `5` to find the missing tensor:

```
tf.scatter_nd(tf.constant([[1], [2]]), tf.constant([2,3]), tf.constant([5]))
# <tf.Tensor: id=98, shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 2, 3, 0, 0])>
```

Then sum the two tensors to get:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=113, shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([12,  2,  3, 1, 8, 22])>
```